# Vsscanf replacement for VS not working

Tags: c++, printf, scanf

Hey all I need to used vsscanf due to the way some legacy code did some format comparing, Microsoft decided they didn't need to include vsscanf so I am stuck trying to find an implementation to it. Found http://www.flipcode.net/archives/vsscanf_for_Win32.shtml as it was one of the first links and it is totally readable and understandable to me, but for some reason I cant get it to work.

Not going to include the implementation of vsscanf because it is in that link. I just copied and pasted it and included the file. Simple code I wanted to run to test it and make sure I got values back that I could access and copy over to other places but I am getting an exception.

First the code I am testing with:

```
int matches = 0;
void** argList = new void*[3];
matches = vsscanf("Hello123Test321", "Hello%iTest%i", (va_list)argList);
```

Exception i get is Unhandled exception at (location) in (project): 0xC0000005: Access violation. It occures when it gets to the sscanf part of the in lining.

```
(Snippit from source found at link above)
void *savedESP;
_asm
{
    mov     savedESP, esp;
    mov     esp, newStack;
    call    sscanf;            //THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION GET THROWN
    mov     esp, savedESP;
    mov     result, eax;
}
```

I feel like whatever I am doing is silly just need someone to point it out to me. I just need make the comparison, make sure there was the correct amount, and have a structure with all the values passed in back.

Thanks

Comment: `Microsoft decided they didn't need to include vsscanf` Uh, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280924.aspx ?

Comment: That `vsscanf` code is horrid. It leaves `sscanf` with precisely zero working stack space (`sscanf` will just overflow into `vsscanf`'s stack space if it needs any), which looks like it'll just blow up awfully at runtime.

Comment: @nneonneo that is what seems to happen indeed, any suggestions as to a better implementation or what I could change?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Sorry vs2010 they didn't put it in their libraries.

Comment: That `(va_list)argList` scares me.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: seriously everything about this scares me. I would say that I don't think the `vsscanf` implementation is sane or that it should be used. (Also, OP: if you are running a 64-bit build then the `vsscanf` is totally wrong and definitely shouldn't be used).

Comment: @nneonneo Help me out then man. I been looking all day for other ones. Dont have another option other than to find an implementation our source code that works. Not really skill nor have the time to write my own.

Comment: `vsscanf` is a fine idea... but trying to build your own va_list, not so fine

Answer (score 0):

You allocate an array of 3 pointers:

```
void** argList = new void*[3];
```

But those pointers do not point to anything. `sscanf` stored the integers it reads in the memory where the pointers point to, but it is random memory.

Before calling `vsscanf`, you probably need to so something like:

```
void** argList = new void*[2];
int* values = new int[2];
argList[0]=(void *)values;
argList[1]=(void *)values+1;
```

But I also think the function will never work. It creates a new stack just for the parameters.

```
mov     esp, newStack;
call    sscanf;
```

But it is very likely that the sscanf function will use the stack, to call other functions or store registers on the stack. To allow that the stack must be much larger. Or better, it should just use the normal stack instead of creating one itself.